# Azure IoT Edge - Offline behaviour for module download

Tags: azure-iot-edge

1. If edge agent is unable to reach a repository where a module is located, will it retry? If it will, what is the strategy for these retries?
2. If a module download is interrupted, what will edge agent do? Will it have a retry strategy, and if so, it will restart the download or will somehow continue where from the point where failure occurred?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it will retry.  The attempt to create module will retry according to backoff schedule, which starts at 5 seconds and increased by 2^(restart count) until the max backoff is 5 minutes.
2. This is mostly done through the container runtime, which downloads by layers. If a download is interrupted, it should restart from the last successfully downloaded layer.